# how to dynamically give id to the textbox

Tags: asp.net, textbox

How to give ID dynamically to the `Textbox` in `asp.net` like

```
<asp:TextBox ID='<% %>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
```

**Update**

```
<table border="1">
<% 
    for (int j = 0; j < dtTasks.Rows.Count; j++)
        {%>
            <%-- other code here --%>
            <asp:TextBox ID='<% "txt" + j.tostring()%>' runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
            <%-- other code here --%>
        <% }%>
</table>
```

Comment: have you put your textbox in list control or what?

Comment: @renish no. . . simple in a table

Comment: Why do you need to do this and what are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: @Justin i have to create texboxs dynamically.. ..  so i use a for loop in my aspx file. see the updated question.

Comment: I do believe this isn't possible using inline code currently.  You will have to use JavaScript to change the Ids or set the Ids in your code behind as part of the initial page load routine.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by using the `Load` handler on the `textbox`.

So for example, set an `OnLoad` event handler; in this case it's called `SetMyTextBox`

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ll" OnLoad="SetMyTextBox" />
```

Then in your code behind create a method to handle this. Then simply set the ID

```
protected void SetMyTextBox(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    ((TextBox)sender).ID = "MyNewID";
}
```

OR you can do this in the code behind.

You can give your textbox an initial ID, say "MyTextBox" and then in your code-behind you can simply do:

```
MyTextBox.ID = "MyNewTextBoxID"
```

Comment: I have to give the id in aspx page not in cs file

Answer (score 0):

put one dummy class in your textbox

```
<asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="MyTextbox"/>
```

then apply id using jquery

```
$(window).load(function () {
     $('.MyTextbox').attr('id', 'txt1');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

apply for loop in your asp view and then give id for each textbox dynamically simple as give specific name and + dynamic variable

```
 @for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                                {
                                    @Html.HiddenFor(m => a model where you want to submit send value,new{id="chkbx" + 1})
                                }
```